# Import library eneim/Toro in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to import "eneim/Toro" in android studio, but every time i get the error Error:Could not find property 'bintray_user' on com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayExtension_Decorated@39913ada.

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.5.4'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.5'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
  apply plugin: 'bintray-release'
}

ext {
  libraryVersion = '2.0.0'
  androidVersion = 24
  buildToolVersion = '24.0.0'
  supportLibraryVersion = '24.0.0'

  minSupportSDKVersion = 16
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
      url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"
    }
  }

  tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
  }

  configurations {
    javadocDeps
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: added the build.gradle in edited question

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to import the library without also trying to use Bintray?

I had success importing the library, without bintray, by importing the RC-2-0-0-4

```
ext {
  toro_latest_version = '2.0.0-RC4'
}

dependencies {
 compile "im.ene.lab:toro-player:${toro_latest_version}"
 compile "im.ene.lab:toro:${toro_latest_version}"
 compile "im.ene.lab:toro-ext:${toro_latest_version}"
}
```

Here is the full configuration I am using in this particular application:

```
ext {
  toro_latest_version = '2.0.0-RC4'
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
 compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.4.0'
 compile 'com.sprylab.android.texturevideoview:texturevideoview:1.0.2'

 compile "im.ene.lab:toro-player:${toro_latest_version}"
 compile "im.ene.lab:toro:${toro_latest_version}"
 compile "im.ene.lab:toro-ext:${toro_latest_version}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the interest. You can now using the latest stable version from jcenter.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Toro lib.